# Получить список таблиц базы данных и ее поля

Tags: postgresql, sql

Имеется несколько баз данных. Как получить список таблиц базы и полей этих таблиц в Postgres?

Answer (score 6):

```
select table_name, column_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema='public'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false;

SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables  where table_schema='public' ORDER BY table_name;

select table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema='public'
```

**Обновление**

```
--PK key
SELECT               
  pg_attribute.attname, 
  format_type(pg_attribute.atttypid, pg_attribute.atttypmod) 
FROM pg_index, pg_class, pg_attribute, pg_namespace 
WHERE 
  pg_class.oid = 'tablename'::regclass AND 
  indrelid = pg_class.oid AND 
  nspname = 'public' AND 
  pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid AND 
  pg_attribute.attrelid = pg_class.oid AND 
  pg_attribute.attnum = any(pg_index.indkey)
 AND indisprimary
```